# Hotmail sometimes sends a page with an error on it, so I cannot access anything. How to fix?

Tags: outlook.com

I need to use a public computer sometime and Hotmail sends a page with an error on it, so I cannot access anything on the page. It says, "Error on the page"' but I cannot get this to change no matter how many times I log in or out. How can I fix this? Why is it happening?

Comment: What browser are you using? Is this an error that Hotmail gives you or does it look like a browser error? Have you tried a different browser to see if that works?

Comment: The browser works on everyother url including another "live" address that I have.

Comment: That answers none of my questions. :(

Comment: I am using Chrome. It looks like a Hotmail error. THe public computer does not allow other browsers. It uses IE.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the public computer's browser or plugins. If so, it would be difficult to fix the issue without proper privileges. One thing you could try is [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/) and use the following:

- **Firefox Portable** or **Google Chrome Portable**
- [jPortable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) for Java VM support.

Comment: +1 for the answer, thanks. The public computer I was using blocked the portable app so no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other information displayed in your browser other than "Error on the page" ??

Have you tried visting Hotmail or the other sites from another Browser on the same Computer ?

If another browser works, then its certainly a problem with browser that you used..
Either switch to the working one, or try re-installing your standardly used browser to see if that fixes it.

If however other browser's also do not work, then it could be an issue with that computer or the Network..

You said it was a public computer, Would you be able to reach out to the Administrator or Owner of that system ? Maybe they are aware of the problem or its some computer/network/firewall setting that they may be able to fix..

Comment: No other info. See my other comments for answers to your other questions.